# Python: Extract values from XML file

Tags: python, xml

I have a XML file and I need to extract some numeric values.
I would like to write a simple Python script, which open/reads the file and
extracts these values. How can I do that?

thank you very much!!!

This is how the file looks like; I want to extract the values inside " "
and save them in an array my_values[].

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
...
...
    <value x="0.000000">
        ...
        ...
    </value>
    <value x="1.000000">
    ...
    ...
....
```

Comment: Explore the `ElementTree` library here - https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 0):

Searching for xml parser, you can find Python sdlib one, or my favourite `lxml`

Install lxml first:

```
from lxml import etree

xmlstr = """
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes" ?>
<xml>
    <value x="0.000000"></value>
    <other_tag/>
    <value x="1.000000"/>
</xml>"""

doc = etree.fromstring(xmlstr.strip())
values = doc.xpath("//value/@x")
print values
```